# Integrate Wt into Qt Creator. How can I change the Qt UI designer parser to make Wt application?

Tags: qt, qt-designer, wt

I want to know if is possible to change the way how the Qt Ui Designers create the C++ code.

For example when I add a pushbutton to the Ui this is converted to

```
pushButton = new QPushButton(centralWidget);
pushButton->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("pushButton"));
pushButton->setGeometry(QRect(70, 90, 97, 27));

void retranslateUi(QMainWindow *MainWindow)
{

    pushButton_2->setText(QApplication::translate("MainWindow", "hola", 0, QApplication::UnicodeUTF8));
```

An I want that the Qt Ui Designer parser convert this text into the next one

```
pushButton = new Wt::WPushButton("Some Text",root());
```